# After "npm i -g npm" my project stopped working

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, compiler-errors

I wanted to install lodash, and official website suggested running

```
npm i -g npm
```

Which I guess updated npm version. After that I ran

```
npm i --save lodash
```

And it outputed this:

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
```

Which I guess changed my package-lock.json file in the project. After that some dependencies issues started and when I tried to run my Angular project it stopped compiling it with an error of:

```
sh: 1: ng: not found
sh: 1: gulp: Permission denied

Process finished with exit code 127
```

Before Gulp started to warn about permission it was only ng: not found which I fixed with "npm link @angular/cli" command. At this point I think I did something completely wrong because I already tried to install newer npm version and it didn't resolve the issue. Anyone have an idea what went wrong here?

Comment: How did you install NodeJS? If you have installed NodeJS system-wide with apt or dnf, you could get into permission issue. I recommend uninstalling system-wide NodeJS installation and use version managers like https://github.com/jasongin/nvs

Comment: You might have permission issues if you have installed `gulp` anf `ng` globally this might help: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally